# MAMP Pro randomly removes hosts from /etc/hosts

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

I have MAMP Pro 4.0.5. Since upgrading to version 4, I have had this intermittent issue where the host entries for my local sites are not output to `/etc/hosts` when a config file save is made. Getting them back is random too, I just keep editing and saving my config from the dashboard until they reappear.

Any ideas greatly appreciated, it really disrupts my workflow.

Answer (score 1):

I get this too with MAMP 4. I thought it might have been the OSX Sierra upgrade.

It seems to re-populate the hosts file if I stop servers, close MAMP, re-open, start servers again.